# How to restrict to only specific threads to run request under controller in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, jmeter-plugins

I'd like to make my test run for 600 users but not more than 2 users should be running the one endpoint "Agro B" under my specified controller. What is the best idea of creating something like this without creating a new simple thread group or concurrency thread group or is it actually preferred way.

[image]

I've tried by creating a throughput controller and specifying 2 users in it but the problem is that after I increase duration time or loops for a thread group those endpoints under throughput controller are not being run more than 2 times in total.

Answer (score 1):

1. The easiest way is just creating another [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 2 users and `Agro B` endpoint.

   The remaining 598 users can go to the Thread Group with `Agro` and `Agro C` endpoints.
2. Alternatively you can go for [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and use the following [__groovy ()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function:

   ```
    ${__groovy((ctx.getThreadNum() == 1 || ctx.getThreadNum() == 2),)}
   ```
3. There is also [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) which ensures that its child(ren) are executed by only one thread at a time but it will ruin your concurrency

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'd understand that the second option with if controller could be the best idea. The first option may be overkill because if I want to scale up my users by uploading jmeter to blazemeter platform it would split the traffic among thread groups. How will I know by using the second option that there will be always 2 threads executing it at the same time since we're looking only for threads 1 and 2 there. I need whoever threads comes first to if controller to join it if there are no more than 2 threads already executing controller http request?